# Use function in str.format or str.format_map

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

When i use `f'my string with {fn("somearg")}'` the `fn(param)` function is called and it's return value is written to the string.

Is it possible, to do the same in `str.format` or `str.format_map` as for example `'my string with {fn("somearg")}'.format(fn=my_function)`

The intention is to format a file, which calls such functions.

Comment: Like this? `"my string with {}".format(fn("somearg"))` ?

Comment: @sj95126 I do not know the order, as I want to format a file which can choose from a variety of these functions....

Comment: This decidedly smacks of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why would you want to do that? Sounds like perhaps you are looking for a templating engine like  `jinja2`.

Comment: @tripleee I tought python will likely use some similar function to `str.format` for this format string literal... ?

Comment: It’s really not clear what you are trying to ask, anyway. Are you looking for `"{foo} {bar} {baz}".format(bar=sqrt(9), foo="Python", baz="rocks")`?

Comment: @tripleee I want to run `'my string with {fn("somearg")}'.format(fn=my_function)` which will result in `my_function(arg)` being called, with whichever argument was defined the string. In your example like `"{foo} {bar(9)} {baz}".format(bar=sqrt, foo="Python", baz="rocks")`

Answer (score 0):

Found out, that the f string literal is defined in the C source code and does not use `str.format` or `str.format_map`.

As current work-around to call functions in a string to format I use:

```py
def format_fnc_support(source_string, format_map) :
    return eval(f'f"""{source_string}"""', globals(), format_map)
```

**I hope, someone comes up with a better solution...**

Example:

```
def my_fnc(v) :
    return v

format_map = {
    'fnc': my_fnc,
    'sqrt': math.sqrt
}
format_this = '{fnc("Python")} {int(sqrt(9))}'

print(format_fnc_support(format_this, format_map))
# Prints `Python 3`
```

Comment: Using `eval` is always inherently unsafe. Don't use that function with any user input.

Comment: @AKX yes, although my question in general, to execute functions in a string (from read file) to format could be considered unsafe (maybe why it is only implemented in string literals?)...